# To check missing values in csv file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large csv file. But for simplicity i have removed many rows and columns. It looks like below:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ? | 27 | 13000 |
| ? | 27 | 13000 |
| validvalue | 30 |  |
| # | 26 | 14000 |
| validvalue | 25 |  |

I want to detect missing values in this csv file. For e.g: missing values indicated in col1 is by **? and #**. In col3 by **empty cells**.
Things would have been easier if the data set has empty cells for all missing values. In that case i could have gone for **isnull** function of pandas dataframe. But the question is how to identify if the columns has other than empty space as missing value.

**Approach if the csv has low number of records**

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
for e in df.columns:
    print(a[e].unique()]
```

This will give us all unique value in that particular columns. But i dont find it efficient.

Is their any other way to detect missing values which are denoted by special characters such as (?,#,* etc.) in the csv file?

Comment: Use the `replace` function on the DataFrame with a `lambda x: x in ['?', '#', '*']` and set the value some `null`. Now all your empty values are `null`

Comment: Thats correct, but in that case i must know that how missing values are represented in the csv file. It could be any other character also ($,@ etc.). i want to detect how missing values are represented in the csv file first. Then later i can replace it.

Comment: You either need to know what's garbage or what's not garbage.

Comment: Does valid data follow some pattern? Does invalid data follow some pattern?

Comment: Ok, got it. I think, there is no way to find the garbage value other than using "unique" function.

Comment: That won't help if there's only one instance of an empty cell since if '?' appears only once it is unique.

Comment: In case you can define a function, perhaps by regex, you can use `applymap` to change the values.

Comment: Can you show me how you can use lambda and replace to replace all the missing values?

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda x: x if ISVALIDCONDITION else None)` will replace any value that is not a valid value with `None`. You can use `def f(x): if ... : return x else: return None` and pass `f` instead of lambda if the function is more complicated than a 1 liner.

Answer (score 3):

As you already stated

> there is no way to find the garbage value other than using "unique" function.

But if the number of possible values is big you might help yourself, using `.isalnum()` to limit the values only to non-alfanumerical strings. For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['?', '?', 'validvalue', '$', 'validvalue'],
                   "col2": [27, 27, 30, 26, 25],
                   "col3": [13000, 13000, None, 14000, None]})

df[~df['col1'].str.isalnum()]['col1'].value_counts()

#Output:
#?    2
#$    1
```

When you will find all possible NA values, you might use `mask` on each column (if missings differ column to column) or on whole dataset, for example:

```py
na_values = ('?', '#')
df.mask(df.isin(na_values))
```